# Android Studio and Keytool - Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Tags: android, keytool, android-keystore

I am aware that many people have had this issue, however I really need some clarification concerning the variety of answers available.

Whenever I try to generate a signed APK in Android Studio, it comes up with 'Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect' and I have tried many of the fixes suggested.

When I try to enter into the CMD:

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\bin\keytool.exe" -storepasswd -new android -keystore "C:\Users\Scott\Desktop\test\Anroid Keystores\SidecarSplit.jks"

I cannot actually type anything in to the 'Enter keystore password', but I can still press enter. Very bizarre!

[image]

Error in Android Studio:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':packageRelease'.
>   com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key SSKey from >store "C:\Users\Scott\Desktop\test\Anroid Keystores\SidecarSplit.jks": Keystore >was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Would really appreciate help getting the APK signed. Thank you

Comment: It's very common for unix/linux tools to display nothing when you type a password. (On Windows I know it would be more typical to display stars or something.) The password entry should still be working fine. (I don't have any other help for you, but I thought you should know that's not your issue.)

Comment: Right - thanks for your help. I suspected that would be the case, but wanted another opinion. Still quite confused about the resulting error though.

Comment: The resulting error is a result of how encryption of the keystore is probably done. First, a hash of the data is usually computed will be added to the payload (sometimes called an envelope). The result is then encrypted with the key. To decrypt, the opposite is done. The payload+hash is decrypted. The block of data that SHOULD be the hash is extracted, and the remainder is hashed and compared to what should have been the hash. If they don't match, it could mean that the key was wrong, or that the encrypted data was changed. There's no way to know for sure which!

Comment: OK, I think I understand what you are saying there. @AviCherry Do you think I should just restart the whole thing with a knew keystore or is there a solution??

Comment: Yes, I think it's doubtful there's anything else you can do other than throw out the keystore and start with a new one.

Answer (score 1):

I solved with that answer of the user Piash Sarkar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46933008/error-generating-certificate-sha-1).

The Password is default : `android`

Answer (score -1):

The only way to solve it was throw out the old one and start again. It seemed as if the keystore was simply corrupted in my case.