# Error Generating Certificate SHA-1

Tags: android, google-api, keystore, sha

I'm trying to integrate my app with the Google API. For this you need to provide the sha-1 of the signing certificate.

At the command prompt, I use the following command provided by Google:

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v \
-alias <your-key-name> -keystore <path-to-production-keystore>
```

With this, I get the following error:

```
erro de keytool: java.lang.Exception: O arquivo da área de armazenamento de chaves não existe. %shang%\.android\debug.keystore
java.lang.Exception: O arquivo da área de armazenamento de chaves não existe. %shang%\.android\debug.keystore
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:745)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:343)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:336)
```

However, the debug.keystore file exists.

[image]

Comment: Use this keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias <your-key-name> -keystore <path-to-production-keystore>

Comment: Thanks. But, asked the password. I solved with resonse of the Piash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For SHA1 Debug Key  , run below command in android studio terminal.**

Mac/Linux :

```
 keytool -exportcert -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

Windows :

```
 keytool -exportcert -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

Replace the %USERPROFILE% with your user path .

The Password is default : `android`

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the SHA-1 key from the studio itself, without using the terminal like this :

- Click on gradle placed at right side of the studio

[image]

- Click on refreshAllGradleProjects button
- go to app
- android
- doble click on signingReport

SHA-1 key will be generated.